# Why can't I use the variance of the sample average in the Central Limit Theorem for the weak-stationary process?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, central-limit-theorem, independence

Under mild conditions $\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2/n}}$ approaches the standard normal (where $\sigma^2$ is the process variance, not the marginal variance $\sigma^2_x$).

Why is the denominator not the standard error for the sample mean of dependent data, specifically
$\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_x^2}{n}\times [1 + 2*\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(1-i/n)*\rho_i]}$
?